# Function to find the index of an element in a list

Tags: list, haskell

Is there a function in Haskell that takes as arguments a list and an element in that list and returns the index of that element in the list, i.e.

If I had the list `['a','f','d','g','b','h']` and the element `'b'` it would return 4?

Comment: Yes, there is. Every computable function is in Haskell.

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5Ba%5D+-%3E+a+-%3E+Int

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the `elemIndex` function in `Data.List`:

```
> :m +Data.List
> :t elemIndex
elemIndex :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
> elemIndex 'c' "abcde"
Just 2
```

Comment: I think that worth teaching the `fromJust` function, too. :) More references at [`Data.Maybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Maybe.html).